# main.cpp calling public virtual method from .h file

Tags: c++, class

```
  class CManagerInterface
  {
      public:
      //--- reports
      virtual TradeRecord* __stdcall ReportsRequest(const ReportGroupRequest 
      *req,const int *logins,int *total)    =0;
  ...
```

The above is in the `.h` file

Now I am in the `.cpp` and I want a `main()`, where I already prepared a `struct ReportGroupRequest` and the logins array, to call `ReportRequest`.

How to call that function?

Documentation says:

"
*

```
CManagerInterface::ReportsRequest
//Gets information about closed positions of clients in order to generate a custom reports.
TradeRecord*  CManagerInterface::ReportsRequest( 
   const ReportGroupRequest*  req,     // Request 
   const int*                 logins,  // List of logins 
   int*                       total    // Number of received records 
   )
```

Parameters
req

[in]  The ReportGroupRequest structure that describes the request parameters.
logins

[in]  The list of logins for requesting information.
total

[out]  The number of records returned by the function.

Return Value

If successful, the method returns a pointer to an array of TradeRecord structures describing trade records. The number of records is added to 'total'. In case of failure, it returns NULL.*
"

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Functions                                                        |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
typedef int (*MtManVersion_t)(void);
typedef int (*MtManCreate_t)(int version,CManagerInterface **man);
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Factory                                                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#ifndef _MT4MANDLL
class CManagerFactory
  {
private:
   HMODULE           m_lib;
   MtManVersion_t    m_pfnManVersion;
   MtManCreate_t     m_pfnManCreate;
public:
   //--- constructor
   CManagerFactory(LPCSTR lib_path=NULL):m_lib(NULL)
     {
      Init(lib_path);
     }
   //--- destructor
  ~CManagerFactory()
     {
      if(m_lib)
        {
         m_pfnManVersion=NULL;
         m_pfnManCreate =NULL;
         ::FreeLibrary(m_lib);
         m_lib=NULL;
        }
     }
   //--- initialization
   inline void Init(LPCSTR lib_path=NULL)
     {
      char path[256]="";
      //---
      if(lib_path!=NULL)
        {
         strcpy(path,lib_path);
         path[sizeof(path)-1]=0;
        }
      else
        {
         #ifndef _WIN64
         strcpy_s(path,"mtmanapi.dll");
         path[sizeof(path)-1]=0;
         #else
         strcpy(path,"mtmanapi64.dll");
         path[sizeof(path)-1]=0;
         #endif
        }
      //---
      if(m_lib)
         ::FreeLibrary(m_lib);
      if((m_lib=::LoadLibraryA(path))!=NULL)
        {
         m_pfnManVersion=reinterpret_cast<MtManVersion_t>(::GetProcAddress(m_lib,"MtManVersion"));
         m_pfnManCreate =reinterpret_cast<MtManCreate_t>(::GetProcAddress(m_lib,"MtManCreate"));
        }
      else
        {
         m_pfnManVersion=NULL;
         m_pfnManCreate =NULL;
        }
      //---
     }
   //--- winsock startup/cleanup
   inline int WinsockStartup() const
     {
      WSADATA wsa;
      return(WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsa)!=0 ? RET_ERROR:RET_OK);
     }
   inline void WinsockCleanup() const
     {
      WSACleanup();
     }
   //---
   inline int IsValid() const
     {
      return(m_lib!=NULL && m_pfnManVersion!=NULL && m_pfnManCreate!=NULL) ? TRUE:FALSE;
     }
   inline int Version() const
     {
      return(m_pfnManVersion?(*m_pfnManVersion)():0);
     }
   inline CManagerInterface* Create(const int version) const
     {
      CManagerInterface *man=NULL;
      if(m_pfnManCreate) (*m_pfnManCreate)(version,&man);
      return(man);
     }
  };
#endif
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks a lot,
Davide

Comment: What function? You've declared it as pure virual. It doesn't exist yet. You need a class that extends `CManageInterface` and overrides it.

Comment: Not to mention you need an object to call the method on. There's so much that is unclear about this problem that it would be easier to understand if you included some of your attempt to call the functions.

Comment: Hi everyone, I didn't create anything else at the moment, what you see here if what I see too. I need to access the class and operate with ReportsRequest and I am not c++ experienced

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings. That function **does not exist**. There must be a class that is derived from `CMamangerInterface` containing that function. Do you have such a class?

Comment: No derivation containing ReportsRequest.,,, There is the Pointer TradeRecord* 
which is a
   
     struct TradeRecord
     {
     }

Comment: @DavideTessarollo Clearly you are using an API that someone else has written, and clearly there is a way to do what you want to do, the problem is that your lack of C++ knowledge means that you are asking the wrong question. What the right question is I don't know.

Comment: See the pointer please... and the guideline I quoted

Comment: @DavideTessarollo So can you talk to the person who wrote this header file? Or can you point to some online documentation about it?

Comment: My question is: how to get a pointer to an array of TradeRecord structures describing trade records via what I wrote?

Comment: @john No, API coder is not available, all he said is reported here. There is no documentation. All you need to know is here, please help me, I need you guys :(

Comment: @DavideTessarollo I understand what you are asking, but there is not enough imformation in the question to answer it. And it seems you don't understand enough to give the extra information

Comment: @DavideTessarollo The thing you need is an object of a class dervied from `CManagerInterface`. Really you need to get that first before you can think about calling the `ReportsRequest` function. But I can't tell you how to get that, it's not specified in the documentation above.

Comment: @DavideTessarollo *All you need to know is here*, unfortunately that's not true.

Comment: in the .h file, there is a collection of structs, amongst which there is TradeRecord, and there is class CManagerInterface, which is public where there is the virtual function ReportsRequest pointing at the TradeRecord data.... I need to populate some array with the TradeRecord via ReportsRequest

Comment: @DavideTessarollo Let's try and get somewhere by starting with the basics. In C++ all methods like `ReportsRequest` must be called on an object. That's very basic C++. What object do you think you are going to use to call the `ReportsRequest` function?

Comment: @DavideTessarollo Is there some function in the header file to get a `CManagerInterface` object? Such methods are often called `getInstance` or something similar.

Comment: @john I added code to the question, please check and tell me if it is of help for moving on. Thank you!

Comment: @DavideTessarollo OK that's helpful. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments the main issue is how to get a `CManagerInterface` object. Now I can see the whole header I see that there's a `CManagerFactory` class. The purpose of that class is to create `CManagerInterface` objects

So you need something like this

```
CManagerFactory factory;
CManagerInterface* intf = factory.Create(version);
TradeRecord* records = intf->ReportsRequest(...);
```

You have already created the reports request parameters (`...`) so you can fill that part in yourself.

Now there's a few things here I don't understand. I don't know what `version` should be, I guess you could just try `0` and see what happens.

The `CManagerFactory` has an optional parameter to some library path, i.e.

```
CManagerFactory factory(path);
```

but again I have no idea what that should be or if it's needed at all.

Hopefully that will get you somewhere.

**EDIT**

Maybe something like this will be a bit better, I've added some error handling, and my best guess at how you get the version.

```
CManagerFactory factory;
if (!factory.IsValid())
    cerr << "invalid factory\n";
int version = factory.Version();
CManagerInterface* intf = factory.Create(version);
if (!intf)
    cerr << "could not create interface\n";
TradeRecord* records = intf->ReportsRequest(...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much... one little issue is that ReportGroupRequest (which is the first parameter of ReportsRequest(...)), requires char name[32] but I give as name a string of much less characters... how to sort it out?

Comment: @DavideTessarollo So I think I'd need to see the declaration of `ReportGroupRequest` to answer that.

Comment: `struct ReportGroupRequest
  {
   char              name[32];           
   __time32_t        from;                
   __time32_t        to;                  
   int               total;
  };`
Thanks @john

Comment: @DavideTessarollo All that means is that you can have **upto** 31 characters in your string, so there's no problem assigning a smaller string. Just do this `strcpy(rgr.name, "something");` and you'll be fine (where `rgr` is the name of your variable).

Comment: @DavideTessarollo C strings use a special character called the nul terminator to indicate the end of the string. Which is why `char name[32];` only allows you to have upto 31 characters. Using `strcpy` ensures that the nul terminator is copied as well well as the rest of the string.

Comment: Not really following that, but this looks wrong `recordsprt = &log_;` The trade record pointer is returned from `ReportsRequest` so you should have something like `recordsprt = intf->ReportsRequest(...);`

Comment: hi so     `TradeRecord record_;
    TradeRecord *recordsptr = intf->ReportsRequest(ptr, logins, recs);
    recordsptr = &record_;`
                                                 
is wrong while...              

 `TradeRecord *recordsptr = intf->ReportsRequest(ptr, logins, recs);`   
      
     is ok and enough?

Comment: @DavideTessarollo Yes the first is wrong. If you look at what that code is it assigns the result of `intf->ReportsRequest()` to `recordsptr` but then it **throws that result away** by assigning to `recordsptr` again. The second is what you want. However there may be some additional code required to discard the results once you've finished with them. But without seeing your documentation I couldn't say what that is.